# add class to button_to rails tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a button tag in my application:

```
<%= button_to"Unsubscribe", cancel_subscription_path, method: :post
      data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, 
      class:"button btn-dash secondary-btn raised ripple no-lh rounded" %>
```

The button seems to work ok and do the action of canceling subscription when I remove the class, but when I apply the class the button doesn't work.

I have tried various forms of encapsulating the class within brackets:

```
<%= button_to"Unsubscribe", cancel_subscription_path, method: :post
      data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, 
      {class:"button btn-dash secondary-btn raised ripple no-lh rounded"} %>
```

But this doesnot seem to do the action of canceling the subscription, but when I remove the class it works. I need it to work with the class.

Comment: I think both these snippets should crash with a `SyntaxError`

Comment: Due to missing space after `button_to` and a comma (",") after first line?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh: the comma. Space is alright (unreadable but syntactically valid)

Comment: Didn't know about the space thing. I think i missed a couple of learning sessions there. :)

Comment: I have just tried to put the action in brackets `<%= button_to("Unsubscribe", {cancel_subscription_path, method: :post, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }}, class:"button btn-dash secondary-btn raised ripple no-lh rounded") %>` but this doesn't work

Comment: Considering the signature of the method `button_to`: `button_to(name = nil, options = nil, html_options = nil, &block)`. Use {} to seperate `options` and `html_options`. `<%= button_to "Unsubscribe", { cancel_subscription_path, method: :post, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } }, {class:"button btn-dash secondary-btn raised ripple no-lh rounded" }%>`

Comment: @JohnBaker that throws a syntax error

Comment: I got it to work with the following instead `<%= link_to cancel_subscription_path, method: :post, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } do %>
                                      <button type="button" name="button" class="button btn-dash secondary-btn raised ripple no-lh rounded">Cancel subscription</button>
                                    <% end %>`

Comment: @GurmukhSingh Ahh the syntax error comes from the brackets it should be like this `<%= button_to "Unsubscribe", cancel_subscription_path, {method: :post, class:"button btn-dash secondary-btn raised ripple no-lh rounded", data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } }%>` . I'm glad you found the solution.